# SQL Server query error: "Missing or incomplete select statement"

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

```
SELECT 
    Id, Product, 
    [fare] = CASE WHEN @date BETWEEN s1from AND s1to THEN s1rate ELSE fare 
FROM Table1
```

Error:

> Missing or incomplete select statement

Answer (score 3):

Haven't you forgot the END keyword at the end of CASE statement?

Ie.

```
SELECT 
    Id, Product, 
    [fare] = CASE WHEN @date BETWEEN s1from AND s1to THEN s1rate ELSE fare END
FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT Id, Product, [fare] =
CASE @date
WHEN BETWEEN s1from AND s1to THEN s1rate 
ELSE fare
END
FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

The query might be like this,

```
Select Id, Product, (case when @date between s1from and s1to then s1rate else fare end)as fare from  Table1.
```

Try this.